# How to include html file inside Pisa document xhtml2pdf with python?

Tags: python, html, pisa

I'm new in xhtml2pdf with python , write html code with python in readable format is somehow cumbersome . I want to know how to include .html file in pisa document.Here is simple code in which I create pdf file:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa   
def main():
    filename = "simplePrint.pdf"    
    # generate content
    xhtml = "<h1 align='center'>Test print</h1>\n"
    xhtml += "<h2>This is printed from within a Python application</h2>\n"
    xhtml += "<p style=\"color:red;\">Coloured red using css</p>\n"          
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(xhtml, file(filename, "w"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If code of html is too large I want to make an another module, place it in myHtml.html file and include in 3rd last line like:

```
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(myHtml.html, file(filename, "w"))
```

How I reach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then what you want is probably another file in the same directory as your above code called `myHtml.py` looking like this:

```
html = "<h1 align='center'>Test print</h1>\n"
html += "<h2>This is printed from within a Python application</h2>\n"
html += "<p style=\"color:red;\">Coloured red using css</p>\n"
```

and then in your above code `import myHtml` in the beginning.

However, I believe it would be better, if you put the html into a html file, called `myTemplate.html` for example. Then you could read the file like this:

```
template = open("myTemplate.html")
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(template.read(), file(filename, "w"))
template.close()
```

Comment: If I want to insert python variable(state) in HTML code.Then how?

Comment: That depends a lot on how sophisticated your insertions have to be. If it's just some strings, you could read the template, have some unique strings there like _%INSERTCOLORHERE%_, then use a regex or simply `.replace()` on the html. If you really want to use the solution using a module, then you can do it there by concatinating the string like usual `html = "<html>"+yourinsertedvariable+"...</html>`

Comment: Ok, well the idea is we make another file `.html` and call it in say `myPiClass.py` class but all the variables of `.myPiClass.py` class is not accessible in `.html` file.Sorry I did'nt get your above answer?

Comment: Well first you must decide what you want to do. Do you want to put all your html code into a variable? This is not a good practice. If you want to do this anyway use the way I describe in the first code block.

Comment: Then you can insert variables there, for example by declaring a function `insertMyVariables(var1, var2)` which sets and returns the html-string: `html = "<h1>"+var1+"<h1> ... return html`" As I said I really don't think you should do it this way.

If you want to do things cleaner you put your html-code into a seperate html file, read it, use `.replace()` on the read string and use it to render your pdf.